# How can I prevent opening new tab will get same URL as existing tab

Tags: macos, safari

I have been using Safari on OS X for a while without much issue until I hit the one described in the title.

Let's say I have a YouTube tab open. If I hit the new tab button and enter YouTube, instead of opening another tab, Safari redirects me to the existing YouTube tab. It is not limited to this website, Stack Overflow behaves the same for example.

I could not find anything in the settings related to this and Google didn't help either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you carefully observe and check if you are not accident picking up the autocompleted URL from the history?

Comment: And what if I am? I don't want that behaviour either way. Also, I should mention that the youtube tab is pinned, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I can confirm this happens to me with a pinned youtube tab. I'm not really clear on the purpose of pinning tabs, but I'm guessing that is the designed behavior. I pinned this question and when I entered "apple.stackexchange.com" it opened a new tab, so I think it only happens when you perfectly match the pinned tab url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so after searching a little more, I found that this is the normal behaviour and it cannot be changed. So the only solution so far is to either accept it or switch browsers. If a better answer is posted, I will approve it.

Comment: Do you know if there is now – about two years later – a way to deactivate this automatic tab switching behavior? Maybe there is a defaults that could be changed in the Safari PList? Or has anybody heard of a Plugin that can fix this stupid behavior?